# Inertia JS error while clicking on a Link

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

**Sometimes** when i click on a Inerta Link the "**All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received**" shows up on a white modal that containing a JSON with props and component name that belongs to login page.

**Sometimes** reloading the page after this error can solve the problem.

Here is the code:

```js
<template>
    <Link href="https://example.com/same-path?page=2">Go to page 2</Link>
</template>

<script>
import {Link} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

export default {
    components: {Link}
}
</script>
```

This is my `App\Http\Kernel.php`:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ... Other middlewares ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
    ],
];
```

The controller:

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $runs = App::make(RunRepository::class)->paginate(15);

        return Inertia::render('panel/runs', compact('runs'));
    }
```

Comment: post your controller and middleware for that route `same-path?page=2`

Comment: I updated the question, Also i don't use any specific middleware for `same-path?page=2`. Everything is as default.

Comment: well, it looks like the error is something related to an un-authenticated request.

Comment: why dont you test returning the request parameter 
`return Inertia::render('panel/runs', [ 'request' => $request] );`

Comment: Because this problem rarely occurs and visitors send us these reports.